# C: structures, easy, full short program code shown

Tags: c, structure

Here is the program. It is fully commented what it aims to do etc. The issues are two:

a) I get the typical error of "data definition has no type or storage class when I create the prototypes of the functions.

b) After entering the input to the scanf question and pressing enter, I still have to type any letter and again press enter to continue through the program, otherwise it just does not progress: Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


/* Object:
 * A program that allows upon user input recreate structures
 * with different names. Except when entering 'n', it will always
 * ask "Do you want to create a new book (structure)? 
 * It is about storing books, title, author, price, and pages */



// 1. I create the blue print of the structure (forget about typedef...)

        struct book {
        char title[100];
        int pages;
        int price;
        char author[50];
        } ;

// 2. I declare some variables

char wants;
char name [30];


// 3. Function prototypes

question();
create_structure_name();


// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                

  create_structure_name(){ 
  printf("Give a name to your structure: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%s\n", &name);  
  printf("you have chosen this name %s for the structure: \n", name);
  struct book name;       

  printf("Title: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%s\n", &name.title);
  printf("The title is %s: ", name.title);       


  printf("Paginas: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%d\n", &name.pages);
  printf("It has this number of pages %d\n: ", name.pages);

  printf("Price: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%d\n", &name.price);
  printf("The price is %d: ", name.price);

  printf("Author: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%s\n", &name.author);
  printf("The author is %s: ", name.author);       
}      

// I define the function ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

question()
{
printf("Do you want to create a new book? :");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c\n", &wants);
     while(wants!= 'n')
     {
         create_structure_name();         
     }             
 }           


// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++        


        main(void)
        {
        create_structure_name();
        question();
        system("PAUSE");

                  }
```

Comment: Never call `fflush(stdin)` - it's UB in most environments (although some allow it).

Comment: `control reaches end of non-void function` this is also a undefined behaviour.

Comment: John, you're not meant to fix your question based on the answer, it makes the answers useless and destroys the whole concept of SO, the Q&A style. Adding minor edits for question clarification is okay but wholesale changes with fixes means the question is no longer in need of solving - it won't help any future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your formatting makes your code not exactly readable.

Secondly `main(` should be `int main(` and return a result

Thirdly, don't call `fflush` on an input stream. It has undefined behaviour.

Fourthly, you use `scanf`. NEVER use `scanf`. EVER. Read a whole line from the console (using `fgets`, not `gets` (which sets you up for another world of pain)) and then use `sscanf` and *please* remember to check the result that gets returned.

Comment: yes, you are right about fgets, I am reading about this, never heard of it before.

Comment: just goes to show that videos on you tube are worth only what you pay for them. Suggest you read a decent book on C programming and your man page, where you'll soon work out that `fgets` takes a buffer, the size of the buffer and the stream (e.g. `stdin`), and `sscanf` takes a string to scan rather than a stream to scan

Comment: I fixed the issue about my wrong way of accepting input and introduced fgets, which can be either to read from a file a whole line or to accept from stdin up to \n. If all the issues are fixed then I think I could give you the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your formatting is odd, and there are many issues.

You need to learn how to write function declarations, especially what a *return type* means.

It should be e.g. `void create_structure_name(void);`.

Another: the global variable `char name[30];` is shadowed by `struct book name;` inside the `create_structure_name` function.

Answer (score 3):

```
question();
```

is *not* a decent prototype. Prototypes should have return types and parameters, such as:

```
void question (void);
```

Ditto for your function *definitions* as well.

Those things may have worked when I was a boy (during the K&R years) but there are much better ways of doing things now :-)

Comment: sure there will be better ways but I have watched one 5 minutes of a youtube video about structures and I wanted to go ahead doing something more useful than writing just one structure with one name. The program allows for infinite new names being created dynamically at run time, and that is cool, though with the issues mentioned. (of course, there should be more code for correcting or deleting user input etc, but so far this is what I have).